# Shopify Migrated Customers Need Account Created Automatically

Tags: shopify, account, shopify-api

I used Cart2Cart to migrate a Volusion store to Shopify.

All customer data and orders came through successfully, but customer accounts were not created. If they try to login or do a password reset they get the "No account found with that email."

I want to create their accounts for them without sending them activation emails. Don't really care about the password as it'll be super complex and they will need to reset it when trying to login, but at least they won't be getting the no account message.

Any ideas? I found https://docs.uselocksmith.com/article/231-approving-customer-registrations which discusses creating a password for the accounts. Waiting to hear back from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This company offers a service where your Shopify store looks for existing customers from your old store and has them "reset" a password when they come back to the store. https://webinopoly.com/blogs/news/migrating-magento-username-password-to-shopify Thus, no need to mass email them and they feel more secure about doing the password reset because they came back to your store on their terms.

Comment: This is as good an answer as I've found. Thank you for the info.